# React JS fetch function not sending any HTTP request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-data-jpa

This very same React APP was working till yesterday and suddenly today it stopped working completely. The fetch is not working at all, it not sending the HTTP request at all as observed the Network tab of Firefox. What is wrong with this? It was the same code that perfectly worked yesterday and suddenly today it stops to work.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Where the hell is server response]

As you can see that there is absolutely no response from the server. Why there is no response code against the POST request, as seen in the first line?

React Code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Login(props) {
  const [email_id, setEmailId] = useState({ email_id: "" });
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const history = useHistory();

  const submit = () => {
    let finalOrder = JSON.stringify(email_id);
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/Project/customer/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: finalOrder,
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        history.push("/AllProducts");
      }
    });
  };
  // sessionStorage.setItem("customer_id", JSON.stringify(result));

  // alert(sessionStorage.getItem("customer_id"));
  // history.push("/AllProducts");

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmailId({ email_id: e.target.value });
  };
  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <form>
      <h3>Sign In</h3>

      <div className="form-group d-flex w-25 p-3 position-relative">
        <label>Email address : </label>
        <input
          type="email"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          value={email_id.email_id}
          onChange={handleEmailChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group d-flex w-25 p-3">
        <label>Password : </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          value={password}
          onChange={handlePasswordChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group d-flex w-25 p-3">
        <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            className="custom-control-input"
            id="customCheck1"
          />
          <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">
            Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button
        onClick={submit}
        className="btn btn-primary btn-block d-flex w-25 p-3"
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

What is this weird behavior? Can anyone help? @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000/") added in the JAVA controller.Thanks in advance.

PS: Getting perfect response in ARC.
[image]

Now it is giving the following error:
[image]

Comment: Was there any error thrown in the console? Code seems to be fine

Comment: - could you add a `.catch` block for your fetch call, and see if you are getting any sort of errors.

- maybe try making a POST call manually with something like `Postman` to figure out if issue is on client or server side, and provide us with more info based on that.

Comment: Getting a perfect response in ARC.

Comment: Error in the console : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: its a cros error.. the ports are different..

Comment: Then why is it not happening for other Components in the same app which are accessing the same REST service?

Comment: Try adding a CORS header to your fetch requests and see how it works. Read this for more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

"Error in the console : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." got resolved automatically by adding **type="button"** to the button. Sounds weird but true.